# Enum Reflections Java

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I know my use case seem silly but this is the easiest way to explain what i need so here it goes

lets say i want to write the following silly generic methods :

```
void toString(Object o);

Object fromString(String enumObject,Class<Enum> classOfTheObject);
```

given :

```
public enum PositionType 
{
    B,
    F,
    L,
    R
}
```

and :

```
PositionType ptype = PositionType.B;
```

how do i go on and implement those methods so that :

```
fromString(toString(ptype),PositionType.class).equals(PositionType.B);
```

would return true?

i tried looking at the [java reflections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/enumSetGet.html), but still i didnt find how to solve it there...

please notice that the implementation must not rely on the specific enum type, it could be any enum type, but for what i need, we can limit ourselves to only enum objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with many solutions, here is one of them (I wrote the strict minimum):

```
String toString(Object o) {
   return ((Enum) o).name();
}

<T extends Enum<T>> Object fromString(Class<T> enumType, String o) {
   return Enum.valueOf(enumType, o);
}
```